# Formatting Text.DateStyle in SwiftUI to Only Show Days

Tags: swiftui

I am putting together a timer app and want the countdown to display how many days until the end of the timer.

`Text(date, style: .relative)` -> ## days, ## hr

The above gets me 90% of the way there but I don't want hours to show up alongside my days counter.

I have tried converting the timer to a string but there is a type mismatch.

I have looked through the documentation [Text.DateStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/datestyle) but it doesn't seem to be a native option.

Comment: The built in function gives you an advantage of adjusting to proper units: days, minutes, eventually minutes and seconds. If this is undesirable, you can always create a custom component: calculate the difference in days (e.g. https://sarunw.com/posts/getting-number-of-days-between-two-dates/) and show it... For the case of days I wouldn't even bother to update it (the chance that number of days switches when user looks at it, is minimal, and nobody has view open for 24 hours)